# POST objects that also contains arrays in database (react, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios, fetch

I am building a web app with react and nodejs. I want to add to the database (json) an object that also contains arrays

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        'name': 'John',
        'age': '32',
        'offers': [
            {
                'a': 'b'
            }
        ]
    });

        axios('http://localhost:3002/clients', {
            method: 'POST',
            data: qs.stringify(formData)
        })
```

, but the result is something like that:

```
{
      "name": "John",
      "age": "32",
      "offers[0][a]": "b",
      "id": 2
    }
```

Any ideas? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: why are you stringifying formData?

Comment: it doesn't work even if I don't use stringify